# Trying to pass query parameter in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, maui, .net-maui.shell

This is the function that changes location:

```cs
string restaurantId = (string)e.Parameter;

Console.WriteLine(restaurantId);

await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"location?restaurantId={restaurantId}");
```

Param is not undefined and it is consoled there. And the page changes, but the query param is empty string:

```cs
[QueryProperty("RestaurantId", "restaurantId")]
internal partial class LocationModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string restaurantId;
       
    public LocationModel() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RestaurantId); // EMPTY
    }
}
```

This is `AppShell.cs` where routes are registered:

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute("login", typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("home", typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("location", typeof(LocationPage));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Properties are not guaranteed to be set in the constructor

Comment: @Jason, then how do I pass a parameter and be guaranteed to retrieve it?

Comment: You just should not assume the property will be available in the constructor.  If you absolutely must have the value in the constructor, pass it as a parameter, not a navigation property

Comment: Read farther down in Maui Shell Navigation doc. It mentions at least two ways to process query parameters.

Comment: Query parameters should be defined on Views (or rather Pages), not Models or ViewModels, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes). The property never gets set in your scenario, because you need to retrieve it in your View and then pass it along to the ViewModel/Model. Where's your Page defined? Can you show the code behind of your Page and where you set up the routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this is to use the `[QueryProperty]` on your `LocationPage` (the *Page*) and **not** on the `LocationModel` (the *ViewModel*), and then pass it along from the Page to the ViewModel.

**LocationPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(Id), "restaurantId")]
public partial class LocationPage : ContentPage
{
    private LocationModel _viewModel;

    public string Id
    {
        set => _viewModel.RestaurantId = value;
    }

    public LocationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new LocationModel();
    }
}
```

**LocationModel**

```cs
public partial class LocationModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string restaurantId;
}
```

This way you can retrieve the *query parameter* and pass it along to the ViewModel. You'll have to implement the logic for loading data in the ViewModel according to the passed `RestaurantId` yourself. You could also do this using a method, such as `Load(string restaurantId)` instead of using a property.

You can read more about how *query parameters* work in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes).